# how to hide sign in with apple button if version iOS 12.4 below

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I have encounter a problem on sign in with apple button
apparently i created a custom UI button class to cater Sign in with apple on storyboard

`@IBOutlet weak var appleSignInbutton: MyAuthorizationAppleIDButton!`

now this button from storyboard causes an error where in it says that the class is available only for iOS 13 + versions.

I just want to hide the button if the iOS version is 12.4 below. is there any better way to implement this? the custom class i created is to cater the sign in with apple which is a feature iOS 13 above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this programmatically:

1. Create your button:

```swift
var btn: MyAuthorizationAppleIDButton!
```

2. In your view did load set its frame and properties. Then you’ll have to add it to your view.
3. Only add it to your view if the device has iOS 13+

```swift
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
  view.addSubview(btn)
}
```

If you want iOS 12.4 replace 13.0, but since (as you said) it’s only available with iOS13+ I’d suggest doing it as I showed you...